# Pass variable from URL through a php login redirect function into wp-login form inputs

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

This is a funny one, but only a genius can probably figure this out. It's an odd one.

Requires a little javascript and a little adjustment to my existing php wordpress function.

I have a wp site that is locked down from the public using this function...

```
add_action('get_header', 'wpq_member_only_site');
function wpq_member_only_site() {

    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {

        $redirect_after_login = get_home_url();

        $login_url = wp_login_url( $redirect_after_login );

        wp_redirect( $login_url, 302 );
        exit;
    }

}
```

...which redirects non-logged in users to the login form.

My question is, I would like use URL variables like this...

**http://example.com?user=media&password=23747**

...and somehow, (I guess) pass it through the function and into the login page URL...

**http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&user=media&password=23747**

...so then a script in my login_head can use, and automatically pre-populate the login form.

I will insert the script into my login_head using this function...

```
function my_login_head() {
  echo '

      <!-- script here -->
  ';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_login_head');
```

Does anyone think they can help me with this? Or know if its possible.

The idea is, so I can use this URL to give people access without them having to know the username or password.

Any ideas or help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Silly question... why don't you just email them the details and send them to the login screen. also. why have a username and password if you are just going o be giving people access without them having an account? that link will no doubt propogate and then others who you havent given access will gain any way...

Comment: It's because I am putting a html file on a memory stick which uses javascript to redirect them to the site. The link also has google campaign code so I can track people who click the file. The people getting the memory sticks will be people with in the general industry. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For url like this...

**http://example.com/wp-login.php?ul=media&up=5434535**

```
function my_login_head() {
        if(isset($_GET['ul'])&& isset($_GET['up'])){
                $ul=esc_attr($_GET['ul']);
                $up=esc_attr($_GET['up']);
                echo '<script>
                        window.onload = function() {
                                var ul=document.getElementById("user_login");
                                ul.value = "'.$ul.'";
                                var up=document.getElementById("user_pass");
                                up.value = "'.$up.'";
                        }
                </script>';
        }
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_login_head');
```

If you want to use an url like:

**http://example.com/?ul=media&up=5434535**

to redirect non members to the prefilled login form, you can use this modifed version of the original 'wpq_member_only_site' function:

```
add_action('get_header', 'wpq_member_only_site');
function wpq_member_only_site() {
        if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
                $redirect_after_login = get_home_url();
                $autofill="";
                if(isset($_GET['ul']) && isset($_GET['up'])){
                        $ul=esc_attr($_GET['ul']);
                        $up=esc_attr($_GET['up']);
                        $autofill="&ul=".$ul."&up=".$up;
                }
                $login_url = wp_login_url( $redirect_after_login ).$autofill;
                wp_redirect( $login_url, 302 );
                exit;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having written this, it seems like you might be able to do this via another method:  Just call the [wp_signon()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon) function, so you don't need to mess around with wp-login.php.  Just wp_signon($credentials) and then wp_redirect($wherever).

You could do this on any page, so your thumb drive technique could link to `site.com/member-login/?query=string`.  `/member-login` would be a custom template that handles this info.

What I might suggest:  create a hash to make this a little more obscure.  Then it would look like:  `/member-login/?x=Ajzf29xjz4jfjAJkdSlj3` or whatever.

Anyway... back to my original answer. It sounds like you're close...

```
wp_redirect('wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&user=media&password=23747');
```

In your login head function, try tracing out these `$_GET` variables to make sure they're coming through.  I don't think jQuery is loaded on this page, so you'd want to echo a jQuery include `<script>` if you're going to use that.

Your login head function:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form selector").val("<?php echo $_GET['user']; ?>");
});
```

Something like that?

**Here's the thing:**

They still have to click the submit button.

You know you can log a user in using a simple function call?
[wp_signon()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_signon)

Comment: Hey mike, thanks for taking the time to answer, this is the first time I heard of signon. Was interesting to take a look as this might come in handy another time. Anyway I solved another way based very similar to your answer but instead not using jquery, just js, and passing it through my original function. Thanks to DBrains. Please see my answer. Again, Thanks for you time.